# Can .lyr files be used without shapefiles?

Tags: layer-file

I've been sent some .lyr files, with no associated shapefiles.

I'm using QGIS, so it seems I need to try some conversions to get these to work anyway - but I just wanted to check before I embark on that journey, if .lyr files are supposed to be used independently of shapefiles?

Or if it would be a normal request to ask for the associated .shps!

Comment: Tangentially related to the OP is the issue of reading .lyr files within QGIS.  There is a product to do that (https://north-road.com/slyr/) , although I have no experience with it.

Comment: Thanks @StuSmith - I've looked this up, but there is a hefty €1200 licence fee for this! Not within budget. Assume there is no other way? Trying to research a bit at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you also need the data (which doesnt have to be a shapefile).

See: [What is the difference between a shapefile and a layer file?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011516)

> if a layer file is sent to a user on another machine without the data
> it was created from, it does not display on the map because it does
> not contain the source data. To get the data to display properly, the
> user must have the layer file and the shapefile it references

Comment: Thanks! I thought that, but have never used an .lyr before and didn't want to appear uneducated with a client!

Answer (score 6):

The real answer is more nuanced than @BERA make it.

In it's true that a .lyr doesn't contain any data but only the reference to the data source and the styling setting associated to it. That mean that you can't open/display a .lyr if you don't have **ACCESS** to the data source.

BUT a .lyr can reference local **OR** online data, if it reference a local data source you need to ask for the source data but if your .lyr reference an online resource you only need an internet connection to open it (and of course ArcMap...).

For example if you go to : [this page](https://carto2.apur.org/apur/rest/services/OPENDATA/HAUTEUR_VEGETATION_2015/ImageServer) and click on "ArcMap" in the "View In" section, you will download a .lyr that will open in ArcMap...